# Make row yellow if $_GET is

Tags: php, html

**Intro**

I have a system when you click edit and submit the form, it will display in the URL as an $_GET with the ID (See the GIF for an example):

[image]

**Now what's the problem?**

I want to have the ROW that has changed (so the `<tr>`) light up yellow so you know what you've edited, I have tried to do this (see the code below) but that didn't do the job.

Maybe you can help me out? My brain hurts of thinking for a solution..

*I added my 'solution' to line 5 (it doesn't work, though.)*

```
$changer = $_GET['id'];
echo "<table border='1' cellpadding='10'>";
echo "<tr><th>ID</th><th>Date</th><th>Message</th><th></th><th></th></tr>";
while ($row = $result->fetch_object()) {
echo "<tr>" . if (isset($_GET['id']) && $_GET['id'] == $changer) { echo ' class="yellow"'; };
echo "<td>" . $row->id . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row->firstname . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row->lastname . "</td>";
echo "<td><a href='records.php?id=" . $row->id . "'><img src='images/edit.png' alt='Edit' title='Edit update' /></a></td>";
echo "<td><a href='delete.php?id=" . $row->id . "'><img src='images/delete.png' alt='Delete' title='Delete update' /></a></td>";
echo "</tr>";
}
echo "<tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td><a href='records.php'><img src='images/add.png' alt='Add' title='Add update' /></a></tr>";
echo "</table>";
}
```

Thanks in advance, fellow stacker.

Comment: Try adding class="yellow" before you end the `<tr>` tag? `<tr class="yellow">`

Comment: This is of course based on the assumption that you have the corresponding css defined correctly.

Comment: You should put the class inside the `<tr>` now it is behind it.. it should be `<tr class="yellow">`

Answer (score 0):

This is because you put your `class="yellow"` outside of your `<tr>`. Right now you have

```
<tr>class="yellow"
```

What you should do is change

```
echo "<tr>" . if (isset($_GET['id']) && $_GET['id'] == $changer) { echo ' class="yellow"'; };
```

to (moving `if` outside of echo)

```
if (isset($_GET['id']) && $_GET['id'] == $changer) { 
    $str = "<tr".' class="yellow"'.">"; 
}
else {
    $str = "<tr>";
}
echo $str;
```

or, you can use a [ternary](http://www.php.net/ternary) operator

Comment: Got that! Nice notice. But it gives me the following error: `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'if' (T_IF) in C:\xampp\htdocs\records\view.php on line 32`

Comment: Which line is line 32?

Comment: You shouldn't use `if` statements in an echo. See edit:

Comment: I'm trying your solution but it doesn't want to understand it.. It will never add the yellow class to the `tr`, even when the `GET` is present in the `URL`, I tried adding `data-test` to the `else {` `<tr>` but it doesn't even add the data tag to it.. so weird.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add the `$str` to the echo. See edit.

Answer (score 0):

You have failed on `<tr class="yellow">...</tr>`, what you've done is `<tr>class="yellow"...</tr>`.
 You could also try to put it automaticly in with `CSS` like this:

```
table tr{background:yellow;}
```

PHP:

```
echo '<tr>';
PHP code to execute inside <tr> tag.
echo '</tr>';
```

or the example could look like this:

```
echo '<tr' . if (isset($_GET["id"]) && $_GET["id"] == $changer) { echo ' class="yellow"> ... </tr>'; };
```

Answer (score 0):

Change `$_GET['id'] == $changer` with `$_GET['id'] == $row->id`

Comment: But then you will have every row yellow

Comment: No, you wouldn't. For example, if `$_GET['id']` is 3, only if `$row->id` is also 3, you will get a yellow row. And there can be only one 3.

Comment: @Mia btw, it should be `$_GET['changeid']` and **not** `$_GET['id']`

Answer (score 0):

Your line#5 should be

```
echo "<tr" . ((isset($_GET['id']) && $changer == $row->id) ? ' class="yellow"' : "") . ">;
```

This is a shortcode for IF this then that. Also, keep in mind, the class attribute must occur before closing of the tr tag opener `<tr ...>`.